# VBA Connecting with Oracle using Integrated Authentication

Tags: oracle, vba, active-directory, adodb

I'm trying to connect with Oracle warehouse using Integrated Authentication (with Active Directory).
To establish connection I use the follow connection string :

```
Cnct = "Data Source=SRPRDN.WORLD; user ID=id; Password=password;"
Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Cnct
```

I've tried for Windows Autentication :

```
Cnct = "Provider=someProvider;Data Source=myOracleDB;User Id=/;"
```

but it rase an error from ODBC manager about lack of proper drivers (I'm using Business Object to log with IA and there is no messages about lack of drivers).

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: The title mentions connecting with SQL Server "using Active Directory", by which you probably mean Integrated Authentication, but then the question text says you want to connect to *Oracle*, and then you mention something about Business Objects, which is just a front-end analysis tool.

Comment: Can you please _always_ post exact error messages...